# Escaping a whole string in mysql/python

Tags: python, mysql

So I'm writing a python script that is updating values in a mysql table. I've run into a small problem where I've discovered that one of my values that I'm updating into the table has a single quote "'"

Here is the piece of python code I am using,

```
    cur3.execute("UPDATE recon SET Name = '%s' WHERE id = '%s'" % (row[1], row[0]))
```

Works great until I get to a Name that is like this,

```
John's Computer
```

I tried doing

```
   cur3.execute("UPDATE recon SET Name = \'%s\' WHERE id = '%s'" % (row[1], row[0]))
```

But that didn't seem to work either. Any idea how to escape whatever is in row[1] completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be doing:

```
cur3.execute("UPDATE recon SET Name = %s WHERE id = %s", (row[1], row[0]))
```

Which is very different from:

```
cur3.execute("UPDATE recon SET Name = '%s' WHERE id = '%s'" % (row[1], row[0]))
```

The top example will be escaped, the other not.

Answer (score 3):

Don't construct SQL queries with string formatting.  Assuming you're using the mysqldb library; the syntax:

```
cur3.execute("UPDATE recon SET Name = '%s' WHERE id = '%s'", (row[1], row[0]))
```

is what you're looking for. Note that you're passing a tuple as the second parameter to `.execute()`, rather than using the `%` operator to do string formatting.

Comment: +1 for this. Building SQL usig python format to substitute literals is a recipe for SQL injection attacks.